# two components with same data but i dont understand why reactJs

Tags: reactjs

Hi everyone i'm trying to learn ReactJs so i want to do a basic application that when i'm clicking on the left button the Quote component displays "left" and "right" for the right button
I'm trying to do it without using classes, i know they are 10000 ways to do it better but I want to understand why it's 'not working'

here ares my files:

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Cards from './components/Cards.js';



function updateQuote(type){
  console.log(type);
}

function App(){
  const [quoteText, setQuoteText] = useState("firstTextBis");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cards quoteText={quoteText} func={updateQuote}/>
    </div>
  );
}




export default App;
```

Cards.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Cards.css';
import Quote from './Quote.js';
import BtnClick from './BtnClick.js';

function Cards(props){
  return (
    <div className="Cards">
      <Quote quoteText={props.quoteText}/>
      <div className="center">
        <BtnClick type={"1"} func={props.func}/>
        <BtnClick type={"2"} func={props.func}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cards;
```

Quote.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Quote.css';


function Quote(props){
  console.log("aa"+props.quoteText);
  return (
    <div className="Quote">
      txt:{props.quoteText}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Quote;
```

BtnClick.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './BtnClick.css';


var funcc;
var btnType;
function BtnClick (props){
  funcc = props.func;
  btnType = props.type;
    return (
      <div className="BtnClick" onClick={cliquage}>
        hi {props.type}
      </div>
    )

}

function cliquage(){
  funcc(btnType);
}


export default BtnClick;
```

my problem is that when i click on the two buttons they all console.log "2"
why the first one is not console.loging "1" ?

thanks

Comment: try adding function cliquage(){
  funcc(btnType);
}
 inside the BtnClick function

Comment: you are passing `updateQuote` but it doesn't work imo

Comment: the console log still return 2..

Comment: Not sure why you are passing props in a such `hard` way!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
import React from 'react';
import './BtnClick.css';



function BtnClick (props){
  var funcc = props.func;
  var btnType = props.type;

  function cliquage(){
    funcc(btnType);
   }

   return (
      <div className="BtnClick" onClick={cliquage}>
        hi {props.type}
      </div>
    )

}


export default BtnClick;
```

if you add var funcc,var btnType outside the BtnClick function, it will be considered as a common property for both BtnClick components. so the last assigned value will be used as the type ( in your case its 2)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are defining `btnType` as `var` in a static context. See the difference between var/let/const: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-and-let-in-javascript/

If you include that variable inside your function component, that should do the trick:

```
import React from 'react';
import './BtnClick.css';

function BtnClick(props) {
    function cliquage() {
        props.func(props.btnType);
    }

    return (
        <div className="BtnClick" onClick={cliquage}>
            hi {props.type}
        </div>
    )

}

export default BtnClick;
```

P.S. Please note, that now you do not need to redeclare the function and the btnType as static, as you have access to them directly from `props`. Also in your work avoid using `var` (except if it is urgently needed) and also avoid static variables declaration.